# How to start processing a file at an offset?

Tags: shell, files

Use case: You've got a multi-GB log file for a whole week, and you need to search for something which happened on Saturday using for example `grep`. Making an educated guess, you assume that starting the search from the middle of the file will more than halve the processing time (since it's definitely not going to have to process the whole of the rest of the file) while not skipping any relevant data. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `dd` along the lines of:

```
dd if=log skip=xK bs=1M
```

which would skip x * 1024 blocks of size 1M (2^20). See `dd(1)` for details on its handling of units.

If you'd like to automate the binary search, assuming your log has the usual formar `<date> [data]` you can pipe the output to `head -n 2`, check the date on the beginning of the **second** line (which - under the reasonable assumption of "normally" long lines - will be complete) and decide what half you want.

Comment: The question asks about checking that no "relevant data" has been missed, which requires also checking the current data to see whether you should seek backwards.

Comment: @ChrisDown I don't think so: *assume that starting the search from the middle ... will more than halve the processing time (...) while not skipping any relevant data*. The assumption is that throwing away the first half is ok.

Comment: @peterph You're right, this is for exploration rather than automated processing.

Comment: I'm sure someone can find an easier way to express this but to expand the dd usage `dd if=testfile skip=\`du testfile | awk '{print $1/2}' | cut -d "." -f 1\` | grep "error string"`

Comment: @sambler du measures the disk usage (which, for example, is affected by block size), not the filesize. If you want to look at the file size, look at `st_size`.

Comment: @ChrisDown I was looking for a way with shell commands, which Sukminders use of stat would be what I was after. As for block size I don't see starting a couple of K either side of centre when your talking multi-GB files will be noticeable when your starting in the centre only to discard data you know won't be relevant. Files small enough that you want exact centre will be small enough to search the entire file.

Comment: @sambler Not all filesystems have block sizes in the kilobytes. Some niche filesystems have substantially larger block sizes.

Comment: `du` usually has some option to output sizes at least in multiples of either 512B or 1KB (if not something richer, like the one from GNU coreutils).

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your data is in chronological order:

1. Get the size of the file by seeking to the end and doing `ftell()`;
2. Divide that result by 2;
3. Use `fseek()` to seek to that location;
4. Seek to the beginning of the next line by calling `getline()` once;
5. Use `strptime()` to find out what date you're currently at;
6. Do a binary search, repeating steps 4 and 5 until you find the line you want.

Comment: Don't forget the usual: *compile, fix most of the most blatant errors in your code, compile, use*.

Answer (score 1):

Get file size and divide by 2. Divide that by 1024 to get KiB. (Or 1024*1024 to get MiB etc.)

```
((fs = $(stat -c %s logfile) / 2 / 1024))
```

Skip and search

```
dd if=logfile bs=1024 skip=$fs | grep blahblah
```

You could further expand on this, if the logfile is *very* consistent with amount of data pr. day by adding a `count=` value to `dd`.

```
((cnt = $(stat -c %s logfile) / 5 / 1024))

dd if=logfile bs=1024 skip=$fs count=$cnt | grep blahblah
```

That would pipe `cnt * 1024` bytes of data at offset `fs * 1024` bytes.

Wrap it all up in a script and do the piping outside the script to grep, temporary file or what ever you want.

Answer (score 0):

consider tail over less.  Tail command has an option to offset by bytes.  For instance to retrieve the last KiB=K of data from the domainnames file and pipe to grep limiting the return records to 50 matches:

```
tail --bytes=1000K domainnames | grep --max-count=50 --fixed-strings --line-number 'yoga'
```

Answer (score -1):

It's not very clear what exactly you want to do and what you mean my “process”. For big files my favourite interactive program is `less`. It handles large files without problems. It can also skip to a particular percentage, e.g. using `30%`. Furthermore, you can search using `/` and `?`.

Comment: Searching in `less` takes an enormous amount of time, much slower than doing a `grep` for the exact same string (I tried).

Comment: If you know what you're looking for then `grep` is definitely the better choice. `less` on the other hand is interactive and it's easy to peek into the file without loading it entirely.